# Java calendar object date time interpretation?

Tags: java, calendar, set, gettime

I've an application that uses java.util.Calendar object. I do multiple set on the calendar object and also based on certain conditions. However, at the end of it all the last calculated date/time value appears different. I then figured out the invoking the set method doesn't compute the values on the calendar object until you invoke get methods. See below from Javadocs

> Getting and Setting Calendar Field Values
>
> The calendar field values can be set by calling the set methods. Any field values set in a Calendar will not be interpreted until it needs to calculate its time value (milliseconds from the Epoch) or values of the calendar fields. Calling the get, getTimeInMillis, getTime, add and roll involves such calculation.

So my question is if there is any mode on the Calendar object that sets the value even before calling getters before setting next value / constant?

The code below works differently if you remove System.out statements.

Declaration -> Calendar computeTime, int skipCycle, int[] days, int dayOfMonth, int weekOfMonth, int monthInYear, int hourToFire

```
    computeTime.add( Calendar.YEAR, skipCycle ); 
    
    computeTime.set( Calendar.MONTH, monthInYear ); 
    System.out.println( "getcomputeTime:2 " + computeTime.getTime() );

    computeTime.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1 );
    System.out.println( "getcomputeTime:3 " + computeTime.getTime() );
    computeTime.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00 );
    System.out.println( "getcomputeTime:4 " + computeTime.getTime() );
    computeTime.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 00 );
    System.out.println( "getcomputeTime:5 " + computeTime.getTime() );
    computeTime.set( Calendar.SECOND, 00 );
    System.out.println( "getcomputeTime:6 " + computeTime.getTime() );

    int maxValue = computeTime.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);        
    weekOfMonth = weekOfMonth < maxValue ? weekOfMonth : maxValue;  
    computeTime.set( Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, weekOfMonth );
    System.out.println( "getcomputeTime:7 " + computeTime.getTime() );


    if( computeTime.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) > days[ 0 ] )
        computeTime.set( Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, weekOfMonth + 1 );
    System.out.println( "getcomputeTime:8 " + computeTime.getTime() );

    computeTime.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, days[ 0 ] );
    computeTime.add( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourToFire );
    System.out.println( "getcomputeTime:9 " + computeTime.getTime() );
```

Comment: If there were such a mode, what code could you possibly write that would be affected by setting that mode?

Comment: How do you know the setters doesn't recalculate if you have to call a getter to know it for sure, but then the getter recalculates ? How can you affirm it was the getter and not the setter that recalculated ? Question is not clear.

Comment: Because the javadocs stated so!!

Comment: @MickeyDonald Perhaps you should post a complete example that we can run to verify.